# Parameter of $S^2\times S^2$

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, curvature, connections

I want to compute the connection and curvature of $S^2\times S^2$ with induced metric in $R^n$. But I dont know how to represent it by equation. So, I can't begin. May I have some hint ?

Comment: @user60589   I dont understand your mean, could you detailly talk about it ? Besides, I write a answer below, I think it is should be right, is it ?

Comment: Sorry it was wrong

Comment: @user60589   Where is the wrong ?  I can't find it .